# Nginx config root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, vps, digital-ocean

I am trying to launch a server and my nginx is testing out okay but I still get the "Welcome to nginx" page when loading it up in the web browser.  my path to my applications public folder is here:

```
home/dev/application/public/
```

and my nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  xxxx.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /home/dev/application/public;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   home/dev/application/public;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
```

I followed the examples as best as I could but it is not loading up my application.  I am sure I am doing my root wrong and I thank anyone who knows what the deal is here.

Comment: just to make sure, this is a rails website? you have `ruby-on-rails` tagged

Comment: I use a bit of ruby as well

Comment: Do you have passenger installed for nginx ?

Comment: yes I do, I installed it before nginx

Comment: don't you need to add `passenger_enabled on;` to enable passenger?

Comment: That is actually line 4 above thanks=D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

`cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
ls -l`

It should contain your config file (Best practise to make a soft link to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/your.conf`)
If `sites-enabled` contains `default`, remove it: `rm default`

After removing, default file and verifying your correct conf file exists, restart the server:

`service nginx restart`

**Creating a Soft Link**

`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your_server_name`

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Aug  3 19:16 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Aug  3 22:43 www.xxxx.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.xxxx.com

Comment: is the output, I rm default and will try your root

Comment: also, I am on step 8 of this tutorial:

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

Comment: Some improvement! now i get a page unavailable! thats a step in the right direction I thinkXD

Comment: What is the location of your_nginx.conf file? I suggest you to move it to /etc/nginx/sites-available folder

Comment: /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

Comment: so something like : cp /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available

Comment: Yes. Copy your conf to sites-available and then create a soft link (see my comment above)

Comment: I just noticed a typo in your conf file: the correct path - /home/dev/application/public   . After restarting nginx, verify it status: service nginx status

Comment: @ZachyBear ping me on twitter. I'll assist you

Comment: I sent you a tweet=D Thanks again for all the help!